# Query for data within a specified range?

Tags: mongodb, eve

Let's say I'm trying to find the documents that have a latitude between 40<=x<=45

`{"latitude":{"$gte":40},"latitude":{"$lte":45}}`

This returns all values which I guess makes sense, but how can I ensure both conditions of the query are met?

Comment: Just use `{"latitude":{"$gte":40, "$lte":45}}`

Comment: This works.  Thanks very much.

Comment: How about with SQL driver?